# How to schedule a time for maintenance tasks for Delta Live Tables?

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, vacuum, delta-live-tables

Here is the documentation from databricks

Delta Live Tables performs maintenance tasks within 24 hours of a table being updated. Maintenance can improve query performance and reduce cost by removing old versions of tables. By default, the system performs a full OPTIMIZE operation followed by VACUUM. You can disable OPTIMIZE for a table by setting pipelines.autoOptimize.managed = false in the table properties for the table. Maintenance tasks are performed only if a pipeline update has run in the 24 hours before the maintenance tasks are scheduled.

Is there any way i can schedule this commands at a particular time ?

currently i see this commands in history of table to run at different times and not during the pipeline run , Is there any way to schedule this ?

[screenshot of history command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ln6a6.png)

in above screenshot , I see DLT maintenance tasks run every 24 hrs , is there a way to schedule these tasks or run multiple times during a day ?

Comment: Provide the details of your approach with screenshots and code, also provide your expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You have the option to create a Databricks Job and set a scheduled time for its execution through the Databricks Jobs interface.

you can schedule maintenance tasks for Delta tables in Databricks using the `OPTIMIZE` and `VACUUM` commands in your notebooks

To set up a schedule for the job, follow these steps:

1. Navigate to the Workflows section in the sidebar.
2. Locate the job name in the Jobs tab within the Name column.
3. Within the Job details panel, click "**Add trigger**" and choose "**Scheduled**" as the Trigger type.
4. Define the period, starting time, and select the time zone.
5. Optionally, enable the "Show Cron Syntax" checkbox to view and modify the schedule using [Quartz Cron Syntax](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html).
6. Save your configuration by clicking the "**Save**" button.

Know more about [Run a continuous job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/workflows/jobs/schedule-jobs#--run-a-continuous-job).

Comment: I am specifically looking for Delta Live Table feature as it mentions that in data bricks documentation  to run maintenance tasks within 24 hrs. Is there any way i can schedule this time or this time will be automatically taken by DLT. I see these settings are table properties , if there is any property that can schedule this in aDLT